# Copying files from Remote desktop metro app

Tags: remote-desktop, windows-8, modern-ui, remote-connection

I'm using Remote desktop metro app to connect to my office computer and I really like it but I can't copy files from the remote machine to my computer as I usually do with Windows RDC. Is this a limitation of the metro app? Is there a way to do it without use the old RDC Windows client?

Comment: Do you have the latest client? There was an update today or yesterday.

Comment: I did not have it but after update is the same. I can copy/paste between remote and local computer.

Comment: @DavidMorenoGarcía - If you can copy and paste what is the problem?  This is likely simply a limitation of the Modern UI application at this time.

Comment: Sorry, that was a typo. I can't* copy.

Comment: Related - https://superuser.com/q/1241837/66282